# Ошибка с SimpleCursorAdapter.

Tags: android, adapter

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TableName, null,null,null,null,null,null);

        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            Log.d("LOG", cursor.getCount() + "");
        }

        String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.Column_Title, DBHelper.Column_Time };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tbTitle, R.id.tbTime };

        SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, cursor, from, to);
        ListView lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        cursor.close();
```

Приложение крашится на строке создания SimpleCursorAdapter. В чём ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если крашится, нужно смотреть в логи.

Comment: Скорее всего, не хватает параметров для конструктора. Нужно добавить параметр flags. А используемый конструктор [устарел с API 11](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter#public-constructors_1).

Comment: показывайте саму ошибку и структуру таблицы